# The number of partitions of a set of size $28$ into $7$ disjoint subsets of size $4$

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I was wondering if anyone can help with this combinatorics question.

> Give, with justification, a simple formula for the number of partitions of a set of size $28$ into $7$ disjoint subsets of size $4$

In an attempt to solve this question I got $$\binom{28}{4,4,4,4,4,4,4} = \frac{28!}{(4!)^7}$$
But not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Hint: to get some ideas do it by brute force for a set of size $6$ partitioning into $3$ disjoint subsets of size $2$ and see what happens.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  What you have counted are permutations of AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - First you shuffle the $28$ in any of the $28!$ ways.
> - Then you can shuffle within each group of $4$ without changing the partition.
> - Finally you can shuffle the $7$ groups without affecting the partition.

Hence
$$
\frac{28!}{(4!)^7 7!}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am slightly confused in why we want to shuffle the 7 groups?

Comment: @MathsWxve: It is not so much that we want to. The thing is that the $28!$ permutations include the possibility of the $7$ groups appearing in different orders, so we have to divide by $7!$ for that reason.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you very much

Comment: @MathsWxve: Happy to help!